# Как правильно организовать работу с Exoplayer 'ом?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

В активити есть 3 и более кнопки, которые проигрывают разые аудио, правильно ли я делаю что в setOnClickListener для каждой кнопки прописываю такой код

```
private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
    val audioSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
        DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "testzone"))
    )
    player.prepare(audioSource.createMediaSource(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/test1.mp3")))
    text.setOnClickListener {
        player.playWhenReady = false
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
        player.prepare(audioSource.createMediaSource(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/test1.mp3")))
        player.playWhenReady = true
    }
```

получается что использую один и тот же объект player, присваиваю ему каждый раз новый инстанс ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this) и присваиваю player.prepare(audioSource.createMediaSource(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/test2.mp3"))) новое аудио.
Правильно ли так поступать, либо есть вариант получше?